# Total in nested array in vue js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

> This the result of my query I want to get the total of `deduction`

```
3: {total_ot: 0, total_days: 96, total_allowance: 0, wrk_id: 3, f_name: "JOHN", l_name: "DOE",…}
daily_rate: 560
date: {2020-09-24: {work_hours: 8, adj_hour: 0}, 2020-09-25: {work_hours: 8, adj_hour: 0},…}
deduction: {1: {amount: 700}, 2: {amount: 700}}
f_name: "JOHN"
l_name: "DOE"
m_name: null
total_allowance: 0
total_days: 96
total_ot: 0
wrk_id: 3
```

> In my computed
>
> ```
>    deducted(){
>   const deducted  = Object.values(this.workersSummaryData)
>   return  deducted.reduce((acc, item) =>{      
>   console.log(item.deducted)    
>   if(item.deduction)
>   return acc + item.deduction;
>   else return acc
>
>       }, 0)
>    }
>
>  },
> ```

Comment: `result of my query` - could you post that in a form that looks like it's in a javascript variable? at the moment, it just looks like something that wouldn't be in javascript

Comment: Based on the deduction object, I think you'll want to `return acc + item.deduction.amount`

Comment: @Jekrb - more like `return acc + Object.values(item.deduction).map(({amount}) => amount).reduce((a, b) => a+b)` - since `deduction` is an object with properties that are objects with a property called amount :p

Comment: Not woriking It gives result  `3200`, Instead of `1400`

Comment: @Jekrb yes can you give an example?

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you give another exmple?

Comment: @NotaPro - once you have VALID input data in the question, I'll do what I can - at the moment there's no way of knowing what your data actually looks like

Comment: @JaromandaX I want the result like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705234/sum-values-in-nested-loop-in-vuejs

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method and get `amount` property to sum it:

```
const sum = Object.values(obj.deduction)
    .reduce((a, {amount}) => {return a + amount }, 0);
```

An example:

```js
let obj = {
    total_ot: 0, total_days: 96, total_allowance: 0, wrk_id: 3, f_name: "JOHN", l_name: "DOE",
    daily_rate: 560,
    date: { '2020-09-24': { work_hours: 8, adj_hour: 0 }, '2020-09-25': { work_hours: 8, adj_hour: 0 } },
    deduction: { 1: { amount: 700 }, 2: { amount: 700 } },
    f_name: "JOHN",
    l_name: "DOE",
    m_name: null,
    total_allowance: 0,
    total_days: 96,
    total_ot: 0,
    wrk_id: 3
};

const sum = Object.values(obj.deduction)
    .reduce((a, { amount }) => { return a + amount }, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Not working to me, I think because Im getting data like this `Object.values(this.workersSummaryData.deduction)` Im using `this`

Comment: If you could put VALID format data in the question then perhaps you could be helped, as it is, the data in the question is not valid javascript so nobody can decipher it except you @NotaPro

Comment: @NotaPro - no .. DATA ... valid, javascript DATA

Comment: @NotaPro try to write `console.log(workersSummaryData.deduction)` before `Object.values` and see what values are shown

Comment: @StepUp the value is `UNDEFINED`

Comment: @NotaPro try to write 1. console.log(this.workersSummaryData) before `Object.values` and see what values are shown

Comment: I got it bro I put my code in methods and get the value from v-for.. and it works !